# how to make a user switch modes between (admin and user) to comment/post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a page with posts, their likes and comments. Users can post on it, page admins can post on it. If a user is also an admin, how can i make the user switch modes (user or admin) and post/comment/like accordingly? how does facebook make it work.

how i can implement such a thing or is there any gem that does this?

I am using Ruby on Rails and devise.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for impersonation with Rails. Maybe [`user_impersonate2`](https://github.com/rcook/user_impersonate2) gem does the trick.

Checks this useful article by Jess Brown: [Allow Admin To Log On As Another User In A Rails App](http://www.brownwebdesign.com/blog/logon-as-another-user-in-a-rails-app).